# how to execute query foreach cell in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to replace whitespace with NULL in every cell in my database. SQL server 2008 r2. I'm looking for something efficient, but looks like cursor is only way?

Comment: Every row of every (char) column of every table of every database in your database server?

Comment: You'll have to use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cursors are NEVER the answer :)

ypercube did the hard part. You need to take that info and iterate through it, executing an update statement for each column in each table. You can do that using a WHILE statement. Here is an UNTESTED example of how you could do this:

```
--Set database to use
USE [MyDatabase];
GO

--Create table variable to hold table/column pairs
DECLARE @table TABLE (
    [Key] BIGINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    [TABLE_NAME] VARCHAR(100),
    [COLUMN_NAME] VARCHAR(100)
);

--Populate table variable
INSERT INTO @table ([TABLE_NAME], [COLUMN_NAME])
SELECT [TABLE_NAME], [COLUMN_NAME]  
FROM  MyDatabase.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE [TABLE_SCHEMA] = 'dbo' 
AND [IS_NULLABLE] = 'YES';

--Initialize counting variables
DECLARE @counter BIGINT = 1;
DECLARE @max BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @table);

--Iterate through each pair
WHILE @counter <= @max
BEGIN
    --Assign the current pair values to variables
    DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100), @ColumnName VARCHAR(100);
    SELECT @TableName = [TABLE_NAME], @ColumnName = [COLUMN_NAME]
    FROM @table
    WHERE [Key] = @counter;

    --Execute dynamic SQL
    EXEC
    (
        'UPDATE [' + @TableName + ']' +
        'SET [' + @ColumnName + '] = NULL' +
        'WHERE RTRIM([' + @ColumnName + ']) = '''';'
    );

    --Increment the counter
    SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END
```

Comment: So funny. I didn't check SO and wrote the same script 1 hour ago. Thank you and @ypercube

Answer (score 2):

First find all tables and columns that are Nullable and of type `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`, using INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM  MyDatabase.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
  AND IS_NULLABLE = 'YES'
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on how you define whitespace.  Will the following work?

```
update mytable set mycolumn = null where len(rtrim(ltrim(mycolumn))) = 0
```

Comment: I need a query to do it in every cell and in every table. not just one column